# On the number of some special components of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In the book "Random Graphs" by Luczak; page 113, theorem 5.5, it's mentioned that if a graph $G$ contains a component with at least two cycles,$-$ the component must
contain a sub-graph which either consists of two cycles connected by a path (or sharing a vertex), or is a cycle with a “diagonal” path.$-$ Then the number of such components is at most $k^2 k!$ on $k$ vertices.
Can someone help me with the proof of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that any graph that is either "two cycles connected by a path" or a "cycle with a diagonal path" contains a path, $P = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k)$, including all of the vertices with an edge $e$ from $v_1$ to one of $v_3, \ldots, v_k$ and an edge $f$ ($\neq e$) from $v_k$ to one of $v_1, \ldots, v_{k-2}$. Then, there are $k!/2$ ways to build the path, $(k-2)$ ways to select $e$ and at most $(k-2)$ ways to select $f$. Thus the number of such graphs is at most 
$$
\frac{k!}{2} (k-2)^2 \leq k! \, k^2.
$$

Comment: @D Poole, Thank you very much for your solution. But I have some questions. 1) Why do we need to divide our vertex set to two? 2) why we can not have edge from v_1 to v_2 and v_k to v_{k-1}?

Comment: @farrokh  1) I am not sure what you mean by divide the vertex set into two. The path $P$ contains *all* of the vertices of the graph. 2) We already have the edges $\{v_1, v_2\}$ and $\{v_{k-1}, v_k\}$ in the path. To create the first cycle, we add $e$ and then to create the other(s), we add $f$.

Comment: @D Poole, Thank you very much! Yes yes I understood.